# Why the cell background color is gone when the user clicks on the cell?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-66i5zh?file=src%2FP6%2FP7Cell.js) is my code.

The demo URL is [here](https://react-66i5zh.stackblitz.io/p7).

**Background:**

I am building a grid that can support selecting the cell(s) by mouse drag.

And the cell background colour will change when a user enters a specific value into the cell.

For example: if a user enters 'a' into the cell, the cell background will be changed to pink.

**The problem:**

Both features are working properly, however, when I click on the last cell of each row, the cell background colour is gone.

I use the following coding to monitor the cell content change and changing the cell background colour accordingly.

```
useEffect(()=>{
  console.log("h0,"+props.children);
  setClassName(props.className);
  setValue(props.children);
},[props.className,props.children]);

useEffect(()=>{
   console.log("h1,"+className);
   let newClassName=className;
   if(activeShiftInfo[value]){
     newClassName+=' '+activeShiftInfo[value].cssClassName;
     setClassName(newClassName);
   }
 },[value]);
```

Unfortunately, both of them cannot works, it there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add props.classname to your second useEffect as a dependency. The second useEffect is not being triggered on mouseEnter like the first one is -> thus the class is being updated in the first useEffect without the second one being triggered.